# SumConvergence with Product$\sum_1^\infty{\frac{1\times3\times5\times...\times(2n-1)}{n!}}$

Tags: series-expansion

```
SumConvergence[( Product[(2 n - 1), {n, 1, infinity}])/n!, n]
```

$$\sum_1^\infty{\frac{1\times3\times5\times...\times(2n-1)}{n!}}$$

However this returns `True` but it isn't true.

So how can I test it ?

Comment: Your product is incorrect. Try `Product[(2 k - 1), {k, 1, n}]`

Comment: Also, note that `Product[(2 k - 1), {k, 1, n}]` can be written more compactly using double factorial (`Factorial2`) notation, i.e., `(2n-1)!!`

Comment: `Infinity`. Not `infinity` for one.

Comment: Also, please use accepted mathematical notation by stating the iteration variable name:  Sum_{n=1}^Infinity.  Without this specification, the mathematical statement of your sum clearly diverges.  Your title, too, should state "sum" rather than "product."